# working of main.m in iphone programing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, program-entry-point, uiapplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to modify the main.m file in your iOS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998342/is-there-any-reason-to-modify-the-main-m-file-in-your-ios-applications)

I am new in the iphone applications development and I want to know why we don't actively use the main.m file in the iphone programming. I saw in the many books the following usage:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:



    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: exact duplicate - [Main.m file use in IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252952/main-m-file-use-in-iphone) and  [Is there any reason to modify the main.m file in your iOS applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998342/is-there-any-reason-to-modify-the-main-m-file-in-your-ios-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS programs *do* start from a `main()` function, usually found in a file called `main.m`. You might have trouble locating this file, because it's normally in a group called `Other Sources`, not the `Classes` group where most code ends up.

In most iOS programs, `main()` does little more than call `UIApplicationMain()`, which creates the application object and runs the main event loop.

I don't know the precise details of why it's done like that, but I'll hazard a guess that a lot of framework-dependent stuff will break if you try to call it before the event loop gets going.

Comment: i know but in the program  we dont write any code on that file. My question is why we dont write any code on that file

Answer (score 0):

The **main.m** is used just as an entry point for your application (it starts from there), the whole life cycle is handled in Objective C classes.
The method **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**, that belongs to Application's delegate, is used to execute code once the app is ready.

ps: you should try to improve your english, since it's hard to read and understand :P

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the main function [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html). It's not that you don't modify the main file, you do it very rarely. I have modified main function in past when I needed a custom UIApplication subclass.

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"CustomApplication", nil);
```

In general programming, you'd never need to modify the main class, however if you have any special requirements, you can go ahead and do that.