# How to get my objective-c client to talk to my python server?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, sockets

So I'm messing around with some iOS dev stuff and wanted to try to send some a string from the Xcode simulator to a server I've got running in python. I've never had two different programming languages talk so I thought that would be cool.

I followed some objective-c socket tutorials online, and this is what I came up with

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL,
                                   (CFStringRef)@"localhost",
                                   5321,
                                   &readStream,
                                   &writeStream);
NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello from obj c"]; //", inputNameField.text];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

Then, on the server side, it's a simple loop that waits for a message and is supposed to print it.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 5321
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
print("Now Listening")
c, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected, Waiting for message...")
while True:
    data = c.recv(1024)
    print(">Recieved: " + str(data))
```

So I thought the [inputStream open]/[outputStream open] commands would correspond to the socket.accept() command in python, and then the [outputStream write:] function would be read by the connection.recv() method in python. This doesn't seem to be the case though because I stepped through with the debugger and the socket.accept() command isn't triggered until the [outputStream write:data] command.

So whats the proper way to do this? How do I get the objective c code to connect to the socket on the python side, and then send strings the socket can receive. I tried sending two different strings back to back, but it's like the write method doesn't trigger the recv() function.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine so I think you are likely making a simple error. Be sure to check the following:

- Start your python script first. From terminal: `python yourfilename.py`
- Run your objective c code after the python server is listening *and* ensure that the code you've shown actually gets executed (i.e. where in your project did you place this code snippet?)
- Make sure that you make your objective c class that contains the code conform to the `<NSStreamDelegate>` protocol

To test your code I just pasted your objective c code in a method in the standard ViewController class you get when starting a new Xcode project. Here is the code:

In ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate>

@end
```

In ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

[self sendNetworkCommunication];

}


-(void)sendNetworkCommunication {

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL,
                                   (CFStringRef)@"localhost",
                                   5321,
                                   &readStream,
                                   &writeStream);
NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello from obj c"]; //", inputNameField.text];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];

}

@end
```

Then I ran the python script from terminal and *then* ran the Xcode project in the simulator:

[image]

You can see the message sent from iOS.

Comment: I wasn't starting the objective c code until after the server said it was listening. The objective c code just runs in a main function.  And I'm 99.99% sure I declared the class as with a NSStreamDelegate. I'm still work right now and won't be able to check until this evening.  On the server side, I get the message that there was a connection, and then waits for the incoming command. This is triggered by the line that tries to send the string "hello from obj c" however, and the actual string never seems to make it to the server. Are you getting different results when you run it?

Comment: Yes. I am getting a different result. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will go through it when I get home. I'm excited to play around with it

Comment: Isn't it just the worst being at work and unable to code?

Comment: Haha I do some coding at work but it's not as much fun as tinkering around with personal projects

Comment: Okay so I just deleted the code I had, and retyped it from scratch with what you had, and it worked. I tried my code beforehand, after making sure I set the view controller as an NSStreamDelegate in the .h file, ran the server first, and then the Xcodeproject, but still didn't see the string server side. The only difference I can see is that your connection stuff was in it's own method, but I don't think that would make a difference, right? Anyway, it's working now and thanks a whole bunch! I can finally move forward with it now!

Comment: Glad it's working. I don't think it's because the code is in its own method, per se, but more likely because you originally had the code in main.m. Where you finally put it will depend on your specific project, but I would stay away from putting things in main.m. Checkout this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998342/is-there-any-reason-to-modify-the-main-m-file-in-your-ios-applications. Also, if the answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer so future visitors will know the issue is resolved. Happy coding.